# BackgroundWorker - reporting progress with "sub tasks"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

A WinForms application with a custom control, `LabelProgressBar`, which has the ability to display both progress and some descriptive text and/or percentage completion. This is done by calling `LabelProgressBar.statusInProgress(string message, int percentageCompletion)`.

One usage of this is as follows:

```
private void import_begin(System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    // first unpack the arguments
    System.Object[] arguments = (System.Object[])args.Argument;
    System.String filename = (System.String)arguments[0];
    System.String why = (System.String)arguments[1];

     // tasks:
     // 1. read excel file and apply changes to model
     // 2. gather changes and format them as XML
     // 3. send request to server
     // 4. commit/rollback changes

      // grab the worker thread so we can report percentage progress
      System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker = (System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker)sender;

     // now do the work
     #region Task1
     Controller.Excel excel = new Controller.Excel(filename);
     try
     {
          // the progress of this needs to be tracked
          overall_result = excel.import_all(out modified_nodes);
     }
     catch (InvalidDataExcetpion invDataEx)
     {
         // deal with it
     }
     #endregion
     worker.ReportProgress(25);

     // complete remaining tasks...
}
```

The event handler for the worker reporting its progress is the following:

```
private void import_progress(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Import percentage completion: " + e.ProgressPercentage);
    labelProgressBar1.statusInProgress("Import", e.ProgressPercentage);
}
```

In short, the `import_begin` method is broken up into several "tasks". These are broken up into "subtasks". Taking the example of the `import_all` method:

```
public Command_Result import_all(out System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.Data_Node> nodes)
        {
            Command_Result overall_result = Command_Result.OK;
            Command_Result this_result;
            nodes = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Model.Data_Node>(excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Count);
            Model.Data_Node destination;

            // the intent is to report the progress of this particular subtask on the basis of how many worksheets have been processed in this for loop
            foreach (OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet worksheet in excel.Workbook.Worksheets)
            {
                this_result = import_sheet(worksheet.Name, out destination);
                nodes.Add(destination);
                if (this_result > overall_result)
                {
                    overall_result = this_result;
                }
            }

            return overall_result;
        }
```

The intent is to have this "subtask" report progress on the basis of how many sheets have been processed in the loop. Calculating a percentage for this is a trivial task, but it is not clear to me how this can be reported back to the `import_begin` method. When this "subtask" is completed, the **overall** task completion (from the POV of the `import_begin` method) should be 25%. Similarly for the other tasks. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Why do you think that it needs to report back to the `import_begin` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import_begin` don't really need to get the update, it can just call the subtasks, *while* also passing the `BackgroundWorker`, so the subtasks are responsible to directly report their progress. If "polluting" the subtasks with `BackgroundWorker` is unacceptable, then create a delegate to call the BackgroundWorker, so your subtasks will then call the delegate instead.

```
private void mainTask(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    var report = new Action<int>(i => worker.ReportProgress(i)); //the delegate
    smallTask1Clean(report); //this one pass the delegate
    smallTask2(worker); //this one directly call background worker
    worker.ReportProgress(100);
}

void smallTask1Clean(Action<int> a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        a(i);
    }
}

void smallTask2(BackgroundWorker w)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        w.ReportProgress(i*80/5+20);
    }
}
```

You can also insulate the subtasks from having to know their part in the larger tasks, in this case, the delegate should take two variables, the current internal progress of the subtasks and the total item it needs to process.

```
private void mainTask(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
    var preTaskProgress = 0;
    var currentTaskTotalPercentage = 0;
    var smarterDelegate = new Action<int, int>((current, total) =>
     {
         worker.ReportProgress(preTaskProgress + (current *currentTaskTotalPercentage/total));
     });

    currentTaskTotalPercentage = 30; //the following task will in total progressed the main task for 30%
    smallTaskClean(smarterDelegate);
    preTaskProgress = currentTaskTotalPercentage; //upate the main the progress before starting the next task
    currentTaskTotalPercentage = 70; //the following task will in total progressed the main task for 70%
    smallTaskClean(smarterDelegate);

    worker.ReportProgress(100);
}

void smallTaskClean(Action<int,int> a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1500);
        a(i,5);
    }
}
```

Comment: the subtasks cannot be broken up like this, as the `import_begin` method is in the View, while the method which completes the subtask is part of the Controller (this app uses an MVC architecture). So, creating delegates looks like the way to go, as you mentioned. Could you please provide an example of this?

Comment: @Al2110 - Why are delegates better than directly calling the `BackgroundWorker`? Also, you have a form-level reference to the `BackgroundWorker`, right? No need to pass anything then.

Comment: @Enigmativity yes, but what if I wanted that subtask method to report it's own percentage? So, in this example, once the subtask has 100% completion, the overall completion would be 25%. But this subtask might be reused as part of another "task", where it might be considered to be 50% of the overall task, if that makes sense.

Comment: "the delegate should then take two parameters, the current count of processed and the total item to be processed" - you're not thinking this through and that's going to confuse the OP.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yeah, I guess I'd need to edit it with an actual example instead

Comment: @Martheen - Careful using integer maths as you get integer results with divides.